# Homomorphism of algebras and Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products

Let A and B be $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras of finite dimension over Q, and let $\mathbb{Q}^{al}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
Show that if $Hom_{\mathbb{C}-algebra}(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}, B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C})\neq \emptyset$, then $Hom_{\mathbb{Q}^{al}-algebra}(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}^{al}, B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}^{al})\neq \emptyset$.

This question is from Milne's algebraic geometry and the solution, according to the appendix of the book, is as follows:

The statement $Hom_{k-algebra}(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} k, B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} k)\neq \emptyset$ can be interpreted as saying that a certain set of polynomials has a zero in k. If the polynomials have a common zero in $\mathbb{C}$, then the ideal they generate in $\mathbb{C}[X_{1},...]$ does not contain 1. A fortiori the ideal they generate in $k[X_{1},...]$ does not contain 1, and so the Nullstellensatz implies that the polynomials have a common zero in k.

Now I am stuck at the beginning of the proof. How one can interpret the above statement as a certain set of polynomials has a zero in k? And also where he uses the algebraic closure of Q. The so-called Nullstellensatz part is obvious but I cannot perceive the main idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Choose bases for $A$ and $B$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now a linear map from $A$ to $B$ is given by a matrix $M$. What is the condition on the coefficients of $M$ for the map to be a homomorphism of algebras? (Use the structure coefficients of $A$ and $B$, i.e., if
$e_1$, $e_2$,... is a basis of $A$, write $e_i\cdot e_j=\sum c_{ijk}e_k$, etc.)